# Creating a JSON string and serializing it

Tags: c#, json

Consider:

```
{
  "Session": "0544dffdrfded",
  "USERSession": "5588strrft235",
  "Id": "984",
  "Field.Type": "SingleField",
  "Fields[0].Name": "ID",
  "Fields[0].fieldType.typeName": "LOG",
  "Fields[0].helpText": "12587",
  "Fields[0].maxlength": 32,
  "Fields[0].name": "LOGIN",
  "Fields[0].size": 20,
  "Fields[0].value": "a",
  "Fields[0].Identifier": "LOGIN",
  "Fields[0].value": "LOGINFIELD",
  "Fields[0].isEditable": true,
  "Fields[1].displayName": "Password",
  "Fields[1].fieldType.typeName": "PASSWORD",
  "Fields[1].helpText": "285887",
  "Fields[1].maxlength": 32,
  "Fields[1].name": "PASSWORD",
  "Fields[1].size": 20,
  "Fields[1].value": "123",
  "Fields[1].valueIdentifier": "PASSWORD",
  "Fields[1].valueMask": "LOGINFIELD",
  "Fields[1].isEditable": true
}
```

I want to a JSON string looking similar to the above JSON parameters. I am using the following code:

```
string jsonString = "{\"cobSessionToken\":'" + Session["cobsessiontoken"].ToString() + "',\"userSessionToken\":'" + Session["usersessintoken"].ToString() + "'\",\"siteId\":'" + Session["siteid"].ToString() + "',\"credentialFields.enclosedType\":'com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle',\"credentialFields[0].displayName\":'Login ID',\"credentialFields[0].fieldType.typeName\":'IF_LOGIN',\"credentialFields[0].helpText\":'111427',\"credentialFields[0].maxlength\":'32',\"credentialFields[0].name\":'LOGIN',\"credentialFields[0].size\":'20',\"credentialFields[0].value\":'" + txtUserID.Text + "',\"credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier\":'LOGIN',\"credentialFields[0].valueMask\":'LOGIN_FIELD',\"credentialFields[0].isEditable\":'true',\"credentialFields[1].displayName\":'Password',\"credentialFields[1].fieldType.typeName\":'IF_PASSWORD'\",\"credentialFields[1].helpText\":'111428',\"credentialFields[1].maxlength\":'32',\"credentialFields[1].name\":'PASSWORD',\"credentialFields[1].size\":'20',\"credentialFields[1].value\":'" + txtPassword.Text + "',\"credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier\":'PASSWORD',\"credentialFields[1].valueMask\":'LOGIN_FIELD',\"credentialFields[1].isEditable\":'true'}";
         Label1.Text= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonString);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does the JSON *have* to be like that? That would be a really, really weird way to represent the JSON. Normally you'd have a `Fields` property which would be an array of two objects, each with properties of `Name`, etc.

Comment: (And I'd strongly recommend against building up JSON like that. Use a JSON API instead, such as Json.NET.)

Comment: you can use **JObject.Parse(jsonString)**

Comment: @PrayashBhatt Go to http://www.newtonsoft.com/json and read the example in the right, then read the documentation.

Comment: Newtonsoft dll is the json.net, they are same. But use it properly. Why are you trying to serialize a string? Serialize an object if you need the json string, if you have already hand-created the json string, no more serialization is required!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to serialize and deserialize an object via the Newtonsoft JSON DLL file. This link provides good samples directly from the source:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Therefore I would recommend to use an object instead of building strings. It's error-prone and the maintanence is not nice.

Comment: I am not using any classes for deserializing the json response.I am directly fetching the response in dynamic variable and deserializing it.I am not aware how to use classes for serializing and deserializing the json

Comment: Therefore you should have a look at Newtonsoft JSON. Cause this would do exactly what you want and sometimes its good to use classes without reinventing the wheel.